# Is there an upgrade guide for the lesser versions of materialize-css?

Tags: npm, material-design, materialize

There isn't another question that answers this from what I've seen.

I need to go from `0.98.2 -> v1-alpha`. The only update guide I can find is from `0.100.2 -> v1`. There are lots of breaking changes between 98 and 100 that I can't find a guide for. Am I stuck trying to debug it based on the changelog?

Comment: did you find any guides to changes the version from 0.98 to 1.0?

Comment: No sorry. I was using a template at the time with materialize and ended up scrapping the front end and recreating from scratch. Sorry I'm not anymore help

Answer (score 0):

I think they added one on their site to help out. It links to:  https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/v1-upgrade-guide.md